# Call to Fragment in pageAdapter can not resolve newInstance methods

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, adapter, instance

In this code, the error is that it cannot resolve the newInstance method in PageAdapter class and it's said never use newInstance in Fragment.java. How can i resolve this problem?

I want to have one page with viewpager and fragment. When sliding the finger, it changes the text of mt text view from String

ListActivity.java

```
package com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp.ListViewPages.Page1;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp.Adaptor.PageAdapter;
import com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp.R;

public class ListActivity1_P1 extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_activity1__p1);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.curl);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_activity1__p1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here is my PageAdapter.java

```
     package com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp.Adaptor;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;

import com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp.R;

/**
 * Created by Farjad on 9/27/2015.
 */
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private  String[] string;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String [] stringstodisplay) {
        super(fm);
        this.string = stringstodisplay;


    }

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0:
                return Fragment.newInstance(0, android.app.Fragment.class.getSigners());

            case 1:
                return new Fragment.instantiate(0, getString( R.string.s1p1));;

            case 2:
                return new Fragment..instantiate(0, getString( R.string.s1p2));;;


        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Fragment.java

```
package com.example.farjad.mymoneyapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Farjad on 9/27/2015.
 */
public class Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private int page;
    private String text;

    public static Fragment newInstance(int page,String text) {

        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("someInt",page);
        b.putString("text", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        page = getArguments().getInt("s",0);
        text = getArguments().getString("someTitle","text");
    }

    public Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_activity1__p1, container, false);

        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + text);
        return v;

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you called your `Fragment` class - `Fragment`, so in the `PageAdapter` it imported the support `Fragment` class instead of the Fragment class you've extended. I would rename your `Fragment` class to anything else (like, `MyFragment`) and let the IDE resolve the dependency for you, but you can also change the `import` statement in the `PageAdapter` class to import your `Fragment` class.